# Mutually exclusive Radio Button: How to define a custom ListView with multiple elements accompany with  a radio button as a single choice?

Tags: android, android-listview, android-linearlayout

PS: the reference link " www.­androidpeople.­com/­android-­custom-­listview-­tutorial-­part-­1" is not available.

Dears, I am trying to create a single choice ListView accompany with mutilple items list on Android by using the below code (1 java main program and 2 xml layout files). However it will shows multiple radiobuttons enabled, this is not my expection, they should be mutually exclusive !

And How to get the position/content(?) of the choiced listview ?

Could you help me review where I was wrong and how to implement it ? Thanks a lot for the Help !

My code lists:
main java code:

```
package list.view;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

public class MultipleItemsListView extends Activity 
{
    private ListView mListView01;
    private SimpleAdapter mSimpleAdapter;
    private List<String> allTxt1;
    private List<String> allTxt2;
    private List<String> allTxt3;  
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        mListView01 = (ListView)this.findViewById(R.id.listView1);        
        updateListView();
    }   

    private void updateListView()
    {      
      allTxt1 = new ArrayList<String>();
      allTxt2 = new ArrayList<String>();
      allTxt3 = new ArrayList<String>();      

      for (int i = 0 ; i<5; i++)
      {
        allTxt1.add("test1"+i);
        allTxt2.add("test2"+i);
        allTxt3.add("test3"+i);        
      }

      if(allTxt1.size()>0)
      {
        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> mylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
        HashMap<String, String> map;
        for (int i = 0; i< allTxt1.size(); i++)
        {
          map = new HashMap<String, String>();
          map.put("txt1", allTxt1.get(i));
          map.put("txt2", allTxt2.get(i));
          map.put("txt3", allTxt3.get(i));                
          mylist.add(map);
        }

        mSimpleAdapter = new SimpleAdapter
        (
            this, mylist, R.layout.items_list  ,
            new String[] {"txt1", "txt2", "txt3",""},
            new int[] {R.id.textView1,  R.id.textView2 , R.id.textView3 ,R.id.radioButton1}
        );
        mListView01.setItemsCanFocus(true);
      //  mListView01.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
        mListView01.setAdapter(mSimpleAdapter);      
      }      
    }
}
```

Layout1:
main.xml

> ```
> <TextView
>     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>     android:text="@string/hello" />
>   <RadioGroup
>     android:id="@+id/radioGroup1"
>     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content" >    
>
> <ListView
>     android:id="@+id/listView1"
>     android:layout_width="match_parent"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
> </ListView>  </RadioGroup> </LinearLayout>
> ```

Layout2:
items_list.xml

> ```
> <TextView
>     android:id="@+id/textView1"
>     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>     android:padding="3dip"
>     android:text="TextView1" />
>
> <TextView
>     android:id="@+id/textView2"
>     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>      android:padding="3dip"
>     android:text="TextView2" />
>
> <TextView
>     android:id="@+id/textView3"
>     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>      android:padding="3dip"
>     android:text="TextView3" />
>
> <RadioButton
>     android:id="@+id/radioButton1"
>     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>     android:layout_marginRight="10dip"/> </LinearLayout>
> ```

Comment: reference here:[link](http://tokudu.com/2010/android-checkable-linear-layout/comment-page-1/#comment-2931) it says, it is the LinearLayout's limitation. Is it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems hard to get the solution/response from our friends. And I had to let progress to go. 
So, I used an alternative to cover this question/problem, and I would like share it below:

I combinded every list items' description(text String)  to One String first. And then, implements the "simple_list_item_single_choice.xml" with this String to build the ListView.

To use this way there are some limitation for my applicaiton, is not the best way for me (only 60% meet my expection.). Hope there is correct method responsed !